How can you change the border radius of a MatButtonToggleGroup in Angular Material 17
Is it possible to override the default styles of the MatButtonToggleGroup?
How can you change the border radius and background color of the MatButtonToggleGroup?


You can overwrite variables for it, for example in main styles.scss file.
To change border-radius there is variable --mat-standard-button-toggle-shape so just set --mat-standard-button-toggle-shape: 1px; for example.
To change background-color of not selected mat-button-toggle there is variable --mat-standard-button-toggle-background-color and for selected mat-button-toggle there is variable --mat-standard-button-toggle-selected-state-background-color.
Example:


.mat-button-toggle-group-appearance-standard {   border-radius: 5px; }

That will change border-radius to 5px, but it is better to change variable to 5px so for example in styles.scss do mat-button-toggle-group {--mat-standard-button-toggle-shape: 5px;}. Material provide this variable so it is easier to customize them.
